# Working with set-length arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C# but have a strong background in ActionScript 3.

In AS3, you can define an array like so:

```
var array:Array = [];
```

And then add unlimited items to that array via `push()`:

```
array.push(1);
```

I've noticed in C# that you need to define a permanent (I think) length for an array, eg:

```
string[] array = {"this","has","a","length","of","six"};
```

Or:

```
string[] array = new string[6];
```

If I try add new items to the array that will fall outside of the length of this array, I'll get an error:

```
array[6] = "failure";
```

I'm finding it hard to go from being able to add/remove items from an array freely, to now having to define a maximum length.

I'm not really sure how this should be approached in a game environment when an array could contain anywhere between 0 and 10000 entities.

1. Do I just make the array length really long to cater for all the realistic amounts of entities I could have?
2. Is there a different way I should store my entities that should be used in C# that I don't know of?
3. Do I write my own class that redeclares the array with a new length and copies the objects from the old array into the new, with 1 free slot left over?

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are of fixed size in C# as you have found out; [Resizing an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) references a new array instance of the specified size and copies the items in the array into the newly referenced instance.

What you are looking for in .NET are the [generic collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172181%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) such as [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), where `T` is a generic type parameter for some type. In the particular case you have highlighted, you would want to use a `List<string>`

```
var strings = new List<string>();
```

now you can add strings to the collection using `Add()`

```
strings.Add("string to add");
```

In C#3, [collection intializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) were introduced so that you can initialize a collection much more succinctly

```
var strings = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3" };
```

When you create an instance of a generic collection, it starts with a default size; the default size for `List<T>` in .NET 4 is 0, although this is increased to 4 when the first item is added (default sizes may vary across different collection types and framework versions, so it sounds like default size is an implementation detail). Collections are generally resized by the framework using a doubling strategy, that is, when the collection has reached capacity and another item is trying to be added, the collection capacity is *usually* doubled - this is taken care of in the implementation of the generic collections and something you don't need to be concerned with.

When you may want to bear it in mind is when you are adding a known quantity of items to a collection or know an order of magnitude of how many items you're going to add. In this case, you may consider using the overloaded constructor of `List<T>` that takes an `int` for a default size

```
var strings = new List<string>(500);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it covers a couple of things that I would more than likely have questioned down the track.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact requirements you could probably use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead.

```
var list = new List<string> { "this", "has", "a", "length", "of", "six" };
list.Add("success");
list[5] = "seven";

Console.WriteLine(list.Count);    // 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `List<T>` in `System.Collections.Generic`. This is just a dynamic array containing objects of type T. You can add things and access items by index.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

// ...

List<int> L = new List<int>();
L.Add(1);
L.Add(99);
Console.WriteLine(L.Count); // prints 2
Console.WriteLine(L[0]);    // prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is the most direct analogy to JavaScript/ActionScript associative arrays - allows sparce indexing, but no meaningful iteration 0,1,....n. SortedDictionary could be an option too.

If you need just normal array that grows and contains all entries - `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Scan through all the classes and interfaces in the [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx). `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are worth a particularly close look right away, but the rest you can come back to in more detail as you learn more. You will find you use lists and dictionaries a lot. Fixed-length arrays still have their place, but if you started with a variant of ECMA-Script like Actionscript, it might take a while before you can see the power that comes with their limitation. Hopefully you won't go overboard the other way and use them fanatically because they can be a few nanoseconds faster in some cases ;)

Ignore the section "Extension Methods" on your first read. The stuff there is really, really useful, so do study it later, but you don't want to be overwhelmed with information and not remember any of it.

System.Collections is less used since .NET2.0 than with 1.1 because for a lot of cases where we had to make do with them, those in System.Collections.Generic are more appropriate. The other namespaces within System.Collections are also full of goodies, but it's a lot easier to understand the point of them once you've grokked lists and dictionaries (and for System.Collections.Concurrent, a few multithreading concepts).

Answer (score 0):

you should use `List< someType >` in the System.Collections.Generic
namespace instead of a set-size array.  This collection will function the way you are used to--allowing you to add/remove items dynamically at runtime and not tie you down to a set size.  you can `Add(), Insert(),AddAt(), Remove(), RemoveAt()`, and many other methods.  nice thing is, it works well with Linq functions too.

```
myList.Where( itm=>itm.PlayerName == "Steve" ) // for example
```

here is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for `List<T>`
there is a nice comprehensive list of the Linq operations towards the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ArrayList<T>`  in `using System.Collections;`

http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist